# The minimum rectangle area that can contain both triangle and circle.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, packing-problem

I got this problem during my interview and I would love to find a good answer to this.

**Problem:** Given a circle radius equal to `r` and an equilateral triangle each side has a length equal to `a` (as in the image below)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuTYL.png). Calculate the minimum rectangle area that can contain both a triangle and
a circle.

- A circle can also contain a triangle and a triangle can also contain a circle inside.
- The lines of the triangle and the circle cannot overlap each other (They can touch each other).
- The triangle can rotate freely.

### [image]

To solve this, I was thinking about 3 scenarios that could happen:

1. The circle is smaller than the inscribed circle of the triangle.
2. The circle is bigger than the circumscribed circle of the triangle.
3. The circle radius is bound between these values.

Here is my code to solve this

```
def my_function(a, r):
    
    diam = r*2
    h_tri = a*math.sqrt(3)/2
    inner_r = a*math.sqrt(3)/6
    outer_r = a*math.sqrt(3)/3

    # Scenario 1: circle is inside the triangle
    if r <= inner_r:
        return a*h_tri

    # Scenario 2: triangle is inside the circle
    elif r >= outer_r:
        return diam**2

    # Scenario 3: The circle radius is bound between these values.
    else:
        return "I don't know"
```

The last scenario is a very tricky one and probably my logic is wrong as well. Do you guys have a different approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of specific values for $r$ and $a$, or even of their size relationship, I think we can at least say the following.

**I.** If the triangle is within the circle, then the smallest rectangle that contains both is the square with area$$2r\times 2r=4r^2$$On the other hand, if the circle is within the triangle, then since $AB=AC=a$, and $CN=\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}$, the smallest rectangle that contains both is$$AB\times CN=a\cdot\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}=\frac{a^2\sqrt 3}{2}$$
[image: triangle in circle and vice-versa]
**II.** But even when circle and triangle are **external** to one another, they can be contained by these same smallest rectangles, as in the two cases below, where in the lefthand figure the altitude of the triangle $$\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}\le OJ-OP=r\sqrt2-r=r(\sqrt 2-1)$$and in the righthand figure where the radius of the circle$$r\le CH-CD=\frac{a}{2}-r\sqrt 3=\frac{a}{2+2\sqrt 3}$$
[image: touching externally, special cases]

**III.** But generally, if triangle and circle are **external** to one another, and placed so that side $AC$ of the triangle, and side $AB$ extended, are tangent to the circle at $J$ and $F$, as in the next figure, [image: circle and triangle in rectangle]then **III,1)**: if  $GC\le EH$, i.e. if $a\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\le2r$, the height $EH$ of the smallest rectangle to contain them will be $2r$. And since $DFA$ is a $30^o-60^o-90^o$ triangle, and $DF=r$ and $DA=\frac{2r}{\sqrt 3}$, then$$FA=\sqrt{DA^2-DF^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4r^2}{3}-\frac{3r^2}{3}}=\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{3}}=\frac{r}{\sqrt 3}$$and the base of the rectangle$$EB=EF+FA+AB=r+\frac{r}{\sqrt 3}+a$$and hence the area of the smallest rectangle is$$EH\times EB=2r\left(r+\frac{r}{\sqrt 3}+a\right)=2r^2+\frac{2r^2}{\sqrt 3}+2ar$$

**III,2:** But if the height of the triangle exceeds the diameter of the circle, i.e. if $GC>2r$, as in this last figure, where $AC$ and $CH\parallel AB$ are tangent to the circle at $J$ and $F$, [image: triangle taller than circle]then the height of the smallest rectangle is$$EH=GC=\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}$$the base is$$HF+FC+CL=r+r\sqrt 3+\frac{a}{2}$$and the area$$EH\times HL=\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}\left(r+r\sqrt 3+\frac{a}{2}\right)=\frac{ar\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{3ar}{2}+\frac{a^2\sqrt 3}{4}$$

Comment: @Apass.Jack By $r/a$ do you mean the ratio of $r$ to $a$? In each case I give an equation for the minimum rectangle in terms of $r$ or $a$ (section I), or both $r$ and $a$ (sections II & III). Are you recommending I put $r$ or $a$, or perhaps $\frac{r}{a}$, on the left side of each equation and everything else on the right? I’m trying to get clear on your suggestion here; in the absence of other answers or comments on the posted question, I confess I was a little uncertain how to interpret it, and decided just to go with what seemed best.

Comment: Suppose you are interviewed. Your answer should end up like this. "If $r\ge \frac2{\sqrt3}a$, then we should put the triangle inside the circle, and the minimum area is ...; if $r\le\frac1{3\sqrt3}a$, then we should ...; if ...".

Comment: I see what you mean now; from the wording of the question, a more appropriate reply would proceed, in each case, from the $r/a$ relationship, to circle/triangle placement, to calculation of minimum rectangle, instead of from placement, to $r/a$, to area calculation. Thanks too for the advice about proper editing.

Comment: You said it better than me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @EdwardPorcella. I can understand the geometric and your math perfectly. However, I still can't prove that this is the smallest rectangle based on the conditions of the problem. Do you have an explanation for why this is the smallest rectangle?

Comment: Depending on which is greater, $2r$ or $\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}$, the smallest rectangle must have one side equal either to the circle’s diameter or the triangle’s altitude. If the triangle is within the circle, or vice-versa, the other side (base) of the smallest rectangle is either $2r$ or $a$. With the triangle and circle external to one another, the height of the smallest rectangle is again either $2r$ or $\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}$, and the base is as calculated in III above. Is this the problem? Not clear how to get triangle and circle as close as possible together side by side? Too much assumption?

Comment: That is not the problem Edward. The only problem for me is the III case when you calculate the area of the rectangle when the triangle and the circle are external to one another, can you give me proof for why this geometric arrangement will give the smallest rectangle possible?

Comment: Are we agreed on the minimum height, and on the math for height and base, but you would like more  proof in case III, 1 & 2 that this  is the minimum base?

Comment: Yes. I am just curious about the proof in case III that this is the minimum base.

Comment: In the figure for III, 1, it seems clear to me that you can’t move the triangle’s tangency point $J$ farther up the circle’s circumference without pushing the side of the rectangle to the right, i.e. increasing the rectangle’s base. It keeps increasing until you’re halfway up the circumference and then goes back to minimum when the triangle side coincides with the “ceiling”. In the figure for III, 2, the circle can’t move down without increasing the base.  And moving $J$ up, increasing the height and decreasing the base, adds more area above than it takes from the left—a net increase in area.